# Can't create package with approval flow

Tags: salesforcedx, package

I'm using Salesforce DX and Second-Generation Package.

When I add an approval flow, `sfdx force:package:version:create` will be Error.
Which error message says that

> ProcessDefinition entity is not supported.

Does anyone know why it happens or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [metadata coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/44)  approval processes are not supported in packaging so that is likely your issue.